# How to create array data from database?

Tags: php, arrays

How to create an array data from database?

I want to show random data by using `array_rand`.

If we create by manual is like this.

`$a = ['http://php.net/', 'http://google.com/', 'http://bbc.co.uk/'];`

Then call it:

`echo $a[array_rand($a)];`

I try to creat same like that, but fail. Here's what I try:

Data from database:

```
$query2 = $db->prepare ("SELECT idc FROM content ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5");
$query2->execute();

while ($value2 = $query2->fetch()) {
    $data_idc[] = $value2['idc'];
}
```

Then I try to create a same code like code above:

`$bank_idc_1 = [ $string_result = "'". implode("', '", $data_idc) . "'" ];`

Then I call it:

`echo $bank_idc_1[array_rand($bank_idc_1)];`

But I get error.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: what do you expect with `ORDER BY RAND()` ? I doubt that you have column named as value returned by `rand()` in your table

Comment: i want to fetch random `id` from idc field

Comment: _“then i try to create a same code like code above”_ - that’s absolute nonsense. You already _have_ an array, you filled it with items in your while loop. Trying to create _PHP code_ at this point makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: if i stright use `array_rand($data_idc);` im get array number, ex: 0, 1,2, etc. what i want is get id value from database.

Comment: Try just `echo $data_idc[array_rand($data_idc)];`

Comment: array_rand() return type is array. Try rand() with count($a).    $a[rand(0,count($a))];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of this line

```
$bank_idc_1 = [ $string_result = "'". implode("', '", $data_idc) . "'" ];
```

Directly go for:-

```
echo $data_idc[array_rand($data_idc)];
```

***Description:-*** Through `while()` loop you are already getting an array so you need to apply `array_rand()` directly on it.

Comment: Ok sorry, my bad

Comment: @ArtOsi  it's fine. No need to say sorry